# Iterate through LocalDate wth Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, java-time

I have three LocalDates (3 last days), and for each date I want to loop through and do some actions:

```
StringBuilder result = "";
for (LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now(); currentDate.isAfter(LocalDate.now().minusDays(3));  currentDate = currentDate.minusDays(1)){
     Page<User> users = userService.getAllUsersByRegistrationDate(currentDate);
     String reportTable = reportService.getReportTable(users, tableTemplate);
     result.append(reportTable);
}
```

How can I replace this code with Stream API or improve readability?

Comment: Using a stream will be an overkill for this task.

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I find no reason to close this question, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Java 8 solution

If you are really stick with [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), all you can do is to create a sequence of `LocalDate` using an `IntStream` of that many days you want to go to past with. Then `mapToObj` to create a relevant `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();
String result = IntStream.range(0, 3)
    .mapToObj(currentDate::minusDays)
    .map(date -> {
        Page<User> users = userService.getAllUsersByRegistrationDate(date);
        return reportService.getReportTable(users, tableTemplate);
    })
    .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

---

#### Java 9+ solutions

If you use [java-9](/questions/tagged/java-9) or later, you can the advantage of infinite Stream and keep generating items until a certain condition is met.

**Three-args** [`Stream.iterate​(T seed, Predicate<? super T> hasNext, UnaryOperator<T> next)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate-T-java.util.function.Predicate-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-)

```
LocalDate threeDaysAgo = currentDate.minusDays(3);
String result = Stream.iterate(
        LocalDate.now(), 
        date -> date.isAfter(threeDaysAgo), 
        date -> date.minusDays(1))
    .map(date -> {
        Page<User> users = userService.getAllUsersByRegistrationDate(date);
        return reportService.getReportTable(users, tableTemplate);
    })
    .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

**A new method** [`Stream::takeWhile(Predicate<? super T> predicate)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-)

```
LocalDate threeDaysAgo = currentDate.minusDays(3);
String result = Stream.iterate(LocalDate.now(), date -> date.minusDays(1))
    .takeWhile(date -> date.isAfter(threeDaysAgo))
    .map(date -> {
         Page<User> users = userService.getAllUsersByRegistrationDate(date);
         return reportService.getReportTable(users, tableTemplate);
    })
    .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

---

All the examples above generate 3 `LocalDate` instances, since today is `2020-10-15`, they will have for past 3 days: `2020-10-15`, `2020-10-14`, `2020-10-13` and offer them for further processing through `Stream<LocalDate>`.

**Disclaimer**: I find the for-loop more readable. Don't expect "converted" for-loop into Stream API adds readability and brevity automatically. For a lot of cases, it doesn't.

Comment: Isn't your collection step same as simply `.collect(Collectors.joining());`?

Answer (score 5):

### LocalDate.datesUntil(LocalDate, Period)

I find your code fine as i stands. If you want to use a stream operation, or you’re just curious how one might look, since Java 9 you may do:

```
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Africa/Timbuktu"));
    today.datesUntil(today.minusDays(3), Period.ofDays(-1))
            .forEach(ld -> {
                System.out.println("Now doing something with date " + ld);
            });
```

Output when running just now:

> ```
> Now doing something with date 2020-10-15
> Now doing something with date 2020-10-14
> Now doing something with date 2020-10-13
> ```

It’s not that well documented that `LocalDate.datesUntil()` works with a negative period, but it does and returns a stream of `LocalDate` objects.

(I know the curly braces in the lambda are unnecessary in this case, but it seems from your question that you wanted to do more than one statement for each date, and so they are necessary, of course. If you only wanted one method call there, you would probably want just one line. `.forEach(ld -> System.out.println("Now doing something with date " + ld))`.)

Documentation link: [`LocalDate.datesUntil()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#datesUntil-java.time.LocalDate-java.time.Period-)

Comment: Wow, didn't know such method exists. It's great it returns `Stream<LocalDate>` so one can continue processing.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, such handy methods were released with Java 9...